# VBA - Listbox Remove all selected and Next Select all

Tags: excel, vba, select, listbox

Can someone please tell me why this code won't read past the first next in the code. I'm trying to remove all the items on the list that I've selected manually, this is working but after that I want it to selected all so I can write the hole list to a sheet but no matter what I do I can't get it to selected all after I removed the items from the list. in fact it wont read past the first next how do I know that, because if I set the clear function just before it will clear the sheet but not if I put it after the next code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    For listIndexCount = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount
        If listIndexCount >= ListBox1.ListCount Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ListBox1.Selected(listIndexCount) Then
            ListBox1.RemoveItem (listIndexCount)
            listIndexCount = listIndexCount - 1
        End If
    Next listIndexCount 
    Sheets("Courses_calc").Cells.Clear
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Start at the end of the list and work backwards to 0: `For listIndexCount = ListBox1.ListCount to 0 Step -1`. My guess is that you're stepping on yourself by incrementing listIndexCount with the `For` statement and decrementing it inside the `If` statement. Just make the loop step backwards and remove the confusion.

Comment: single-step the code and you will find out